# recv() function doesn't read the input (Socket Programming)

Tags: c, string, sockets

This is a simple program that simulates a credential validation server. Clients should connect using telnet to the server on port 80. The client should enter a username and a matching password. The problem is that the `recv()` function does not seem to receive the right input (so that further processing can be done on it).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{

    char * credentialsList[7][2] = {{"Alice","abcdef"}, {"Bob","1234567"}, {"Cindy","qwerty"}, {"David","abababab"}, {"Eve", "cdefgh"}, {"Frank","7654321"}, {"George", "12341234"}};
    int serverSocket=socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    int new_socket, i;
    char *message, client_message[10];
    struct sockaddr_in server, client;
    server.sin_family =  AF_INET;
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    server.sin_port = htons(80);
    bind(serverSocket, (struct sockaddr *)&server, sizeof(server));
    listen(serverSocket,2);
    int c = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
    new_socket = accept(serverSocket, (struct sockaddr *)&client, (socklen_t*)&c);
    message = "Welcome! You Are Now Connected To The Server.\n\n";
    write(new_socket, message, strlen(message));
    message = "Please Enter A Valid Username: ";
    write(new_socket, message, strlen(message));
    memset(client_message,0,sizeof(client_message));
    recv(new_socket, client_message, 10, 0);
    //int x = strcmp(client_message,credentialsList[0][0]);
    //printf("%i", x);

    puts(client_message);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You need to provide the client code.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala you can connect to it using `telnet localhost 80`

Comment: The problem is you are assuming your username is zero-terminated - well guess what, it is pretty hard to send zero-terminated strings using telnet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How do you detect the end of the username? Is it detected by the end of the connection, by a newline or perhaps by a `'\0'` character? It's impossible to answer this since you didn't provide the client code.

Anyway, you're not checking the return value of `recv()` and the commented-out implicitly assumes that it's a `'\0'`-terminated string which may not be true. You should always check the return code of system calls and never assume the client data to be formatted according to a certain format.

What you need to do is to read the credentials and nothing else. This may even require reading 1 byte at a time until you reach the newline if it's newline-delimited (a more efficient implementation of this would be the implementation of a buffering layer on top of `recv()`). Note that reading the credentials may require multiple `recv()` calls as the credentials may arrive in 1-byte-sized TCP segments.